# Haskell help to understand this State monad code: where is runState defined?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I am new to Haskell and trying to understand monads. I am going thru [this code](https://github.com/sdiehl/wiwinwlh/blob/master/src/02-monads/state_impl.hs)
Putting it here for quick reference

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }

instance Monad (State s) where
  return a = State $ \s -> (a, s)

  State act >>= k = State $ \s ->
    let (a, s') = act s
    in runState (k a) s'

get :: State s s
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)

put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)

modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
modify f = get >>= \x -> put (f x)

evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
evalState act = fst . runState act

execState :: State s a -> s -> s
execState act = snd . runState act
```

I didn't get where the function `runState` is defined. It seems its type is declared in `newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }`.
The most puzzling part is this code compiles without any error.

Where is `runState` defined? where is its code?

Comment: When you define `data T = T { f :: Int -> Int }` the compiler *defines* a function `f :: T -> Int -> Int; f (T x) = x` for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is the functionality provided by *record syntax*. In Haskell, there are multiple ways to define a data type. You are probably familiar with statements like the following:

```
data MyType = MyType String Int
```

where a type `MyType` is defined, which is a sum type (i.e. any value of this type has *both* the `String` and `Int` fields filled). If we want to work with this type, we might want to view the `String` and `Int` components separately, so we would define accessor functions for this:

```
getLabel :: MyType -> String
getLabel (MyType s _) = s

getNum :: MyType -> Int
getNum (MyType _ i) = i
```

For large data types (with many fields) this can get very tedious, and writing this kind of function is in general very common: often we have a simple type where a constructor wraps the content, and we want a convenient way to access this content in its "own" type (i.e. without the wrapper).

Because this desire to access fields is so common, Haskell provides record syntax. When you use record syntax, you essentially name the fields inside a data type, and the functions to extract the values in these fields are generated automatically. So we could redefine our data type from earlier:

```
data MyType' = MyType' { myLabel :: String, myNum :: Int }
```

and Haskell would generate the accessor functions `myLabel :: MyType' -> String` and `myNum :: MyType' -> Int` automatically. These functions then have the same functionality as the `getLabel` and `getNum` functions we defined earlier.

Taking the `State` type as an example, we could have defined it as follows:

```
newtype State' s a = State' (s -> (a, s))
```

and written a function to access the contents:

```
getStateFun :: State' s a -> (s -> (a, s))
getStateFun (State' f) = f
```

which would allow us to remove the `State'` "wrapping" from around our value. But this is less convenient than using record syntax, which is used in your example: the value stored inside the `State` wrapper is given the fieldname `runState`, and Haskell generates the accessor function, which is why the code compiles and runs without problems. `runState` then basically does the same as `getStateFun`.

This is also all quite clearly explained in the section "Record syntax" in [this chapter from *Learn You A Haskell For Great Good*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

Answer (score 13):

Yes you are right it's defined here:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

basically from a definition like this you get two *functions* for free:

- `State :: (s -> (a,s)) -> State s a` the constructor (named the same as the type) - here you can *wrap* in a function into the `newtype`
- and `runState :: State s a -> (s -> (a,s))` (same as `State s a -> s -> (a,s)`) from inside the record-syntax - this will take the *wrapped* function out of the first argument and apply it to the second argument (or return the function back - currying enables us to work with both interpretations nicely)

In a sense, **you** write its code when you create a new `State s a` value - it will take this value, get to the *content* and apply it.

So, for example, if you do

```
runState get "Hello"
{ def. get }
= runState (State (\s -> (s,s))) "Hello"
{ apply runState }
= (\s -> (s,s)) "Hello"
{ apply }
= ("Hello", "Hello")
```

---

to your question - as far as I understand it - the record syntax is equal to this:

```
newtype State s a = State (s -> (a,s))

runState :: State s a -> s -> (a,s)
runState (State f) s = f s
```

Comment: I am still confused. `runState :: s -> (a,s)` is just type signature. Can you give an explicit definition of `runState` function for the code I have given above? I don't understand the _free_ definition the compiler might be generating for me.

Comment: @mntk123 I added something like this - do you understand now?